# How to find if a 2D vector contains a duplicate row?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector, duplicates

I want an elegant way to check if

```
(myvector[0][1] != myvector[1][1] != myvector[2][1]) && (myvector[0][0] != myvector[1][0] != myvector[2][0])
```

etc..I know this isn't how you compare values with an if statement... I figured storing variables into a vector would be the fastest way to properly compare the values as there is a lot of variables that must not equal each other

Edit: Maybe I'm not being that clear, basically I want [x][0],[x][1] to never match [y][0],[y][1]...if either [0] or [1] is different, then it's fine but if ANY of the two pairings match up, then return false.

```
{0,0},
{1,1},
{0,1}
```

is ok, thus passes the duplicate test

```
{0,0}, 
{1,1},
{0,0}
```

failed because there is two pairs of 0,0

The reason so, is because the first row will have values between 2-14 and the second will have values between 0-3. These values represent a 52 card deck and I do not want cards to repeat

Comment: Consider swapping your array dimensions. Iterating over the last dimension is a lot faster because of data locality.

Comment: Can you check it at insert time? Or do you need to check it during runtime in a changing vector?

Comment: What is the size of your sample ? Is your sample sorted ?

Comment: How I would check at insertion? It's anywhere between 5x2 to 7x2 variables

Comment: Do you only want to check for this case or do you wish to prevent it?

Comment: I wish to prevent [x][0] and [x][1] to ever have the condition where both values match up against another set, so [x][0],[x][1] must never equal [y][0],[y][1]...if either [0] or [1] are different, then it's fine.

Comment: So to understand it correctly, you have a matrix, in which each row must contain unique elements?

Comment: must contain unique pairings, as updated

Comment: I have clarified as best as I can editing out what was confusing, and yes it does matter..I've updated the question with my test case

Comment: how does your first example in your second edit pass?  There are clearly pairs of sequential numbers which are the same.  Please rewrite your question from scratch instead of a series of edits.  It's just making it harder to follow.

Comment: And 1,0 and 0,1 are different pairs?

Comment: yes, I added brackets...sorry this problem was hard to properly conceptualize as I'm still rough with vectors and multidimensional array handling

Comment: And with rows you mean columns?

Comment: @PierreAntoineGuillaume in case you're curious about the stuff on my answer that I deleted... http://quick-bench.com/LMGjlz3NZiL5bemYr4QXBbCzdE8  The vector is insanely better (10x) than the BST/set solution.  and still quite a bit better (5x) than an unordered_set: http://quick-bench.com/Bee-plJEhTOmhrI5tnWnWgS7YcQ (note, these are solutions to the question as I interpretted what was originally asked)

Comment: xaxxon i will look the video even though i think i know what it will say. mind i answer to you later here ?

Comment: @PierreAntoineGuillaume sounds good, but I'll spoil it for you:  "Don't use std::map/set" :-D  Chandler Carruth is a great speaker/presenter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a benchmark of a simple solution using a std::vector vs std::map (in another answer here).  You can see here that the vector solution is 6x faster(for a small data set):

http://quick-bench.com/-fOG_uDO6HRPKqOMgxqchqUXHbo

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

constexpr int width=2;
constexpr int height=16;

static void vector(benchmark::State& state) {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> data;

    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    data.emplace_back(std::vector<int>());
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        data[i].push_back(count++);
    }
    }
    while (state.KeepRunning()) {

    std::vector< std::pair<int,int>>m;        // Map key can be a pair and value can be boolean
    m.reserve(height);
    bool unique = true;
    for(int i=0;i<height;i++)
        {
        if(std::find(m.begin(), m.end(), std::make_pair(data[i][0],data[i][1]))==m.end())    // if pair is not already present in array insert the element in map
            m.emplace_back(std::make_pair(data[i][0],data[i][1])); // nothing to do here
        else
            {
            unique=false;    // else pair was already present in array
            break;           // break the loop
            }
        }
    if(!unique) {
        std::cout<<"unexpected match found";
    }

    }

}
BENCHMARK(vector);

static void set(benchmark::State& state) {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> data;

    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    data.emplace_back(std::vector<int>());
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        data[i].push_back(count++);
    }
    }

    while (state.KeepRunning()) {

    std::map< std::pair<int,int>,bool>m;        // Map key can be a pair and value can be boolean
    bool unique = true;
    for(int i=0;i<height;i++)
        {
        if(m.find(std::make_pair(data[i][0],data[i][1]))==m.end()) {    // if pair is not already present in array insert the element in map
            m[std::make_pair(data[i][0],data[i][1])]=true;
        } else {
            unique=false;    // else pair was already present in array
            break;           // break the loop
        }
        }
    if(!unique) {
        std::cout<<"unexpected duplicate found";
    }
    }
}
BENCHMARK(set);
```

Changing the code to use `std::unordered_map` makes it even worse -- a 10x slowdown over `std::vector`:  http://quick-bench.com/aSKrpaW4cZoL2mYJFjy6x1dEvDo

(though I may be hashing poorly)

There may be some optimizing that could be done on the map solution, but it still won't make the map solution faster with this size data set.

The two algorithms seem to even out at around 250 pairs, but there are also further optimizations that can be done on the vector solution to make it scale better.

Comment: Vector is better only for small input size. If the size is high map is preferred like in the above code only changing the height to 10000, then map is 1000x times faster than vector. [Source](http://quick-bench.com/jpdO3omPUVRYpwNHEtIgxH1cAOg)

Comment: Yes, for larger data sizes, you'd want to use an efficient hashing implementation, such as this:  https://github.com/Tessil/hopscotch-map which is around an order of magnitude faster than std::map for both large and small values of N.

Comment: The above code just verifies that vector is better map only if input size is 10 or 20. But if input size is 10000. Map is far better than vector!!

Answer (score 1):

Use [map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). It will take [O(N)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) space and O(LogN) to search an element if it is present in the map or not. [map.find()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) helps to find element if present in the map in LogN time. In your case, the element can be a [pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair).

Here's a sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int i,j,n=3,m=2;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
       for(j=0;j<m;j++)
            cin>>a[i][j];
    }
    map< pair<int,int>,bool>m;        // Map key can be a pair and value can be boolean 
    bool unique = true;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(m.find(make_pair(a[i][0],a[i][1]))==m.end())    // if pair is not already present in array insert the element in map
            m[make_pair(a[i][0],a[i][1])]=true;
        else        
        {
            unique=false;    // else pair was already present in array
            break;           // break the loop
        }
    }
    if(unique)
        cout<<"true";
    else cout<<"false";
    return 0;
}

Input:
0 0
1 1
0 1
Output:
true

Input:
0 0
1 1 
0 0
Output:
false
```

Comment: remember, O(n) isn't a speed, it's a scaling.  std::map is almost always a very bad data structure to use if you are worried about speed.  This is an interview question type of answer, not a production code kind of answer.  On top of map being dog slow, you're doing MULTIPLE map lookups per iteration which is even worse because you've probably purged the previous entries from cache by the time you come back around to them.

Comment: @ishpreet as you can see here, a vector is far superior: http://quick-bench.com/-fOG_uDO6HRPKqOMgxqchqUXHbo  std::map/unordered_map/set/unordered_set are almost always the wrong thing to use if you care about real world performance.  A proper open addressing hash table (which std::unordered_map is NOT) is a good data structure, but unfortunately there is no such thing in the STL.

Comment: My attempt to change your solution to use an unordered_map is slower than map -- from 6x worse than vector to 10x worse than vector: http://quick-bench.com/aSKrpaW4cZoL2mYJFjy6x1dEvDo

Comment: @xaxxon the lookup time of unordered map is **O(1)**

Comment: @ishpreet remember, big-oh isn't a time at all, it's a scaling.   In this case it's constant, but quite slow.   Linearly scanning the vector is much faster because it is extremely cache friendly.  std::unordered_map is a bunch of buckets with a linked list of results in them.  It's quite bad.  If STL had a proper open-addressing hash table, it would be pretty good for this problem, but no such data structure is present.

Comment: The moral of this story is, if you care about performance at all, never use std::map/unordered_map/set/unordered_set.  Either use std::vector or roll your own (or download something else)

Comment: Looks like these two algorithms are even at around 250 pairs:  http://quick-bench.com/Dh8UMUMA8Vf8V0ngHJcMc00nOFg

Comment: @xaxxon Just change your height to 100000 you will see the real difference Look at this http://quick-bench.com/jpdO3omPUVRYpwNHEtIgxH1cAOg

Comment: @ishpreet yes, but the std::map solution is still far slower than the answer requires.   That's the important thing to remember.   Any time you're traversing a linked list (even if it's only a log-N length linked list) you're going to get very poor performance compared to the alternatives

Comment: Running your map algorithm with the open-addressing hash table from here:  https://github.com/Tessil/hopscotch-map and height=100000, gives the following results on my laptop (can't easily get the hash library onto the benchmark website):   vector: 4013 std::map: 47  hopscotch-map: 9.   For height=16, the timings are (in a different scale): 368, 3119, 1186)  - so, again, the moral of the story is:  Don't use std::map/unordered_map/set/unordered_set if you care about speed.   Either use vector (for small data sizes) or roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are representing a deck of cards, have you considered using enums with bit sets? With that, you can store a combination of cards into a single number and easily compare them. In case of large sets that exceed the precision of `int` (`int` has 32 bits), use a `std::bitset<N>`, where `N` is the number of items in the set.

```
#include <iostream>

enum Deck
{
    Jack =  2 << 0,
    Queen = 2 << 1,
    King  = 2 << 2,
    Ace   = 2 << 3
};

void compare_hands(const int hand1, const int hand2)
{
    if (hand1 == hand2)
        std::cout << "Same hand" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Different hand" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int hand1 = Jack  | Queen;
    int hand2 = King  | Ace;
    int hand3 = Queen | Jack;

    compare_hands(hand1, hand2);
    compare_hands(hand1, hand3);
    compare_hands(hand2, hand3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: while Ishpreet answered the question, I'll just redo my code to do this, this looks way cleaner than constantly using multidimensional unsigned short vectors